# How to remove spaces in CSV

Tags: python-3.x

Below is the current code that yields extra spaces after appending logs/events:

```
import csv

#MANUAL ENCODES

logs = [["TT5134", "XACG2M756B2ZP0", "2055243", "ref die", "abort;play", "closed"]
        ]

#FILE DUMP

with open(r"\\xcl3090dm1\checkout_eagle\ETS\PE_Downs(DONOTDELETE)\SR_Data.csv", "a") as csv_file:

    reports = csv.writer(csv_file)

    reports.writerows(logs)
```

Assuming I have next logs/event to input, there will be space produce. How can I use the strip() function on my existing code? I tried to insert this function but I either failing to remove the space or producing errors.

[image: logs with row spaces]

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("\xcl3090dm1\checkout_eagle\ETS\PE_Downs(DONOTDELETE)\SR_Data.csv", sep=',',header=0)
```

If necessary:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: hi thank you, all I need to do is to add parameter newline='' in open function. Already solved my question! :)

Comment: Post as an answer =)